# How to customize email look that I send with nodemailer in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have nodemailer in my application for sending 2 kind of emails, one is for reset password and second is for contact support. How can I make those 2 kind of emails styled like I would do in regular HTML files? I guess that there is I way to customize html in mailOptions but I can not figure out how. I saw something with handlebars but is that the only way or is there any other? And if it's the only way how to pass variables in that handlebar? Variables like subject and text and date for each email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending ejs template using nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304922/sending-ejs-template-using-nodemailer)

Comment: Nodemailer has a good template feature.  https://email-templates.js.org/#/?id=render-html-andor-text

Comment: Yea it does. Thank you so much. I just needed any guide that shows how to do it. Thank you once again. :)